# How to create a Document Library with Metadata Column using JSOM

Tags: managed-metadata, client-object-model

I am trying to automate the creation of a document library.

Therefore I have a button which after clicking on it creates a new document library with at least one managed metadata column. I already created a script which works until I want to add a document to the library and set the metadata, because then the metadata field is greyed out. I have to manually choose the term set in the library settings. Then it works, but I want it already chosen/set with this script.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function createDocLib() {
        var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        var web=context.get_web();
        var list=web.get_lists();
        var docLibCreation;

        docLibCreation = new SP.ListCreationInformation(); 
        var docLibTitel = $('#docLibTitle').val();
        docLibCreation.set_title(docLibTitel);
        docLibCreation.set_templateType(SP.ListTemplateType.documentLibrary);
        var savedList = list.add(docLibCreation);

        var newCols = [ 
            "<Field Type='TaxonomyFieldType' DisplayName='Location' Name='Location' 
                    StaticName='Location' ShowField='Term1033' Open='false'  Group='People' 
                    TermSetId='b49f64b3-4722-4336-9a5c-56c326b344d4' 
                    TextField='155963e0-be13-4b91-bb2b-df69fdcbbeec' 
                    SspId='0d9b6833f2694bb4a3bbe47fb4f6b770' />",
            "<Field Type='Note' DisplayName='Location_0' 
                    ID='{155963e0-be13-4b91-bb2b-df69fdcbbeec}' ShowInViewForms='FALSE' 
                    Required='FALSE' Hidden='TRUE' CanToggleHidden='TRUE' Group='People'/>"
        ];

        var numberCols = newCols.length;
        for (var i=0; i<numberCols;i++){
            this.newColumns = savedList.get_fields().addFieldAsXml(newCols[i], true, SP.AddFieldOptions.defaultValue);
        }
        context.load(this.newColumns);
        context.executeQueryAsync(onDocLibCreationSuccess,onDocLibCreationFail);
    } 

    function onDocLibCreationSuccess() {
        alert("Document Library created");
    }

    function onDocLibCreationFail(sender, args) {
        alert('Failed to Create the Document Library. Error:' + args.get_message());
    } 
</script>

<label for="docLib">
    Name of the Document Library: <input type="text" placeholder="Name of the Document Library" id="docLibTitle" />
</label><br/>
<button onclick="createDocLib()">Create Document Library</button><br/>
```

Why isn't the metadata termset automatically set and choosable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following schema syntax for provisioning a managed metadata field:

```
<Field Type="TaxonomyFieldType" DisplayName="Location"  ShowField="Term1033" Required="FALSE" EnforceUniqueValues="FALSE"  StaticName="Location" Name="Location" >                           
  <Default />                  
  <Customization>                     
     <ArrayOfProperty>
         <Property><Name>SspId</Name><Value xmlns:q1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" p4:type="q1:string" xmlns:p4="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">b5b6effd-4925-43e4-ad43-a257213dedec</Value></Property>                       
         <Property><Name>TermSetId</Name><Value xmlns:q2="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" p4:type="q2:string" xmlns:p4="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">b49f64b3-4722-4336-9a5c-56c326b344d4</Value></Property>                     
         <Property><Name>TextField</Name><Value xmlns:q6="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" p4:type="q6:string" xmlns:p4="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">{155963e0-be13-5b99-bb2b-df69fdcbbeec}</Value></Property>                                            
         <!-- ... -->
     </ArrayOfProperty>
  </Customization>               
</Field>
```

### How to provision a managed metadata field via JSOM

```
var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var web = context.get_web();
var list = context.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle);

var taxField =  
        '<Field Type="TaxonomyFieldType" DisplayName="Location"  ShowField="Term1033" Required="FALSE" EnforceUniqueValues="FALSE"  StaticName="Location" Name="Location" > \
             <Default /> \
             <Customization> \
                <ArrayOfProperty> \
                  <Property><Name>SspId</Name><Value xmlns:q1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" p4:type="q1:string" xmlns:p4="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">b5b6effd-4925-43e4-ad43-a257213dedec</Value></Property> \
                  <Property><Name>TermSetId</Name><Value xmlns:q2="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" p4:type="q2:string" xmlns:p4="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">b49f64b3-4722-4336-9a5c-56c326b344d4</Value></Property> \
                  <Property><Name>AnchorId</Name><Value xmlns:q3="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" p4:type="q3:string" xmlns:p4="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</Value></Property> \
                  <Property><Name>UserCreated</Name><Value xmlns:q4="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" p4:type="q4:boolean" xmlns:p4="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">false</Value></Property> \
                  <Property><Name>Open</Name><Value xmlns:q5="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" p4:type="q5:boolean" xmlns:p4="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">true</Value></Property> \
                  <Property><Name>TextField</Name><Value xmlns:q6="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" p4:type="q6:string" xmlns:p4="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">{155963e0-be13-5b99-bb2b-df69fdcbbeec}</Value></Property> \
                  <Property><Name>IsKeyword</Name><Value xmlns:q8="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" p4:type="q8:boolean" xmlns:p4="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">false</Value></Property> \
                  <Property><Name>CreateValuesInEditForm</Name><Value xmlns:q9="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" p4:type="q9:boolean" xmlns:p4="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">false</Value></Property> \
                </ArrayOfProperty> \
               </Customization> \
          </Field>';


list.get_fields().addFieldAsXml(taxField, true, SP.AddFieldOptions.defaultValue);
context.executeQueryAsync(function() {
       console.log("Managed metadata field provisioned successfully");
    },
    function(sender, args) {
       console.log(args.get_message());
    }
);
```

> Note: there is no need to specify explicitly a secondary field since
>   it will be provisioned automatically.