# Adding the metadata to a taxonomy column in JSOM

Tags: javascript, jsom, taxonomy

I am struggling getting taxonomy into a metadata column using JSOM. I cannot find any great learning manual for JSOM.

```
var fieldSchema = `<Field Type="TaxonomyFieldTypeMulti" 
                           Name="SessionTopics" 
                           DisplayName="Session Topics"
                         Required="TRUE" 
                        Group="Limited Document Library" />`;

    fields.addFieldAsXml(fieldSchema, false, SP.AddFieldOptions.AddFieldInternalNameHint);
```

this creates the site column, pretty easy but now I want to add the taxonomy term into the column using JSOM. I have found plenty of information on how to update a column, but to actually assign a term into the column, I am really struggling. HELP!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try using below JSOM code:

```
var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var web = context.get_web();
var list = context.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle);

var taxField =  
        '<Field Type="TaxonomyFieldType" DisplayName="Location"  ShowField="Term1033" Required="FALSE" EnforceUniqueValues="FALSE"  StaticName="Location" Name="Location" > \
             <Default /> \
             <Customization> \
                <ArrayOfProperty> \
                  <Property><Name>SspId</Name><Value xmlns:q1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" p4:type="q1:string" xmlns:p4="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">b5b6effd-4925-43e4-ad43-a257213dedec</Value></Property> \
                  <Property><Name>TermSetId</Name><Value xmlns:q2="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" p4:type="q2:string" xmlns:p4="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">b49f64b3-4722-4336-9a5c-56c326b344d4</Value></Property> \
                  <Property><Name>AnchorId</Name><Value xmlns:q3="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" p4:type="q3:string" xmlns:p4="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</Value></Property> \
                  <Property><Name>UserCreated</Name><Value xmlns:q4="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" p4:type="q4:boolean" xmlns:p4="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">false</Value></Property> \
                  <Property><Name>Open</Name><Value xmlns:q5="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" p4:type="q5:boolean" xmlns:p4="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">true</Value></Property> \
                  <Property><Name>TextField</Name><Value xmlns:q6="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" p4:type="q6:string" xmlns:p4="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">{155963e0-be13-5b99-bb2b-df69fdcbbeec}</Value></Property> \
                  <Property><Name>IsKeyword</Name><Value xmlns:q8="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" p4:type="q8:boolean" xmlns:p4="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">false</Value></Property> \
                  <Property><Name>CreateValuesInEditForm</Name><Value xmlns:q9="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" p4:type="q9:boolean" xmlns:p4="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">false</Value></Property> \
                </ArrayOfProperty> \
               </Customization> \
          </Field>';


list.get_fields().addFieldAsXml(taxField, true, SP.AddFieldOptions.defaultValue);
context.executeQueryAsync(function() {
       console.log("Managed metadata field provisioned successfully");
    },
    function(sender, args) {
       console.log(args.get_message());
    }
);
```

**Reference**: [How to create a Document Library with Metadata Column using JSOM](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/109987/how-to-create-a-document-library-with-metadata-column-using-jsom)

Comment: Also check the field schema given [here](https://cann0nf0dder.wordpress.com/2014/10/24/creating-a-site-column-with-managed-metadata-using-javascript/) if it helps.

Comment: Hi @Jason, Have you tried this? Is it working for you?/